# Nodejs - Trying to save a Blob to fileserver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, blob

I'm having trouble trying to save a Blob to my file server.

What I'm trying to do is to capture a video from the user's webcam, then display it on the client-side, and then post it on to the fileserver where I can access it.

Here is the code to create a .webm Blob that is displayed at the end of the recording

```js
function embedVideoPreview(optional_url) {
    var url = optional_url || null;

    var video = document.querySelector('#video-preview video') || null;

    var webmBlob;

    if (!video) {
        video = document.createElement('video');
        video.autoplay = true;
        video.controls = false;
        video.loop = true;
        video.style.width = canvasW + 'px';
        video.style.height = canvasH + 'px';
        document.querySelector('#video-preview').appendChild(video);
    } else {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
    }

    if (!url) {
        webmBlob = Whammy.fromImageArray(frames, 1000 / 60);
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(webmBlob);
    }

    video.src = url;


    //here, i post it to my server through a form
    var videoURLSource = document.createElement('input');
    videoURLSource.id = 'videoURLSource';
    videoURLSource.name = 'videoURLSource';
    videoURLSource.type = 'text';
    videoURLSource.value = url.slice(5);
    submitForm.appendChild(videoURLSource);

    var blobSource = document.createElement('input');
    blobSource.id = 'blobSource';
    blobSource.name = 'blobSource';
    blobSource.value = webmBlob;
    submitForm.appendChild(blobSource);
}
```

So I save both the url used in the src attribute of the  element, and here is what happens on the server side -i write it on the disk and save it on a mongoDB database through mongoose:

```js
app.post('/submit', function(req, res, err){

    //getting the data from the POST
    var receivedAnswer = req.body.answer;
    var receivedURL = req.body.videoURLSource[0];
    var receivedBlob;

    //getting all chunks of the blob
    receivedBlob += req.body.blobSource[0];

    fs.writeFile("test.webm", toSaveBlob, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('file written to disk');
    });

    //putting the data submitted into a mongoose schema
    var a = new Answer({answer: receivedAnswer, url: receivedURL, blob: receivedBlob});
    res.send('submitted reponse: '+ receivedAnswer + '<br/>' + 'url:'  + receivedURL + '<br/>' + 'blob:'  + receivedBlob);

    a.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log('Saved : ', data);
    });
});
```

What happens is that a test.webm is indeed written in my current directory, but is only a few bytes, instead of the several megabytes expected.

So my guesses are that I'm saving the first chunk without saving the rest, but I looked around and haven't figured out a way to do that when responding to a POST request.

I'm also unsure whether the form API supports the passing of Blobs.

I've looked into web sockets, but it's something that I know nothing about, so I'd rather try to figure it out another way and worse comes to worst, I'll try using sockets if there's no other way.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using some sort of bodyParser, I'd guess something like Busboy, and then `.on('data')` etc to capture the chunks ?

Comment: Hello! I guess this is a part of what I was missing, but I've also realized my problem might just be in what I'm trying to do overall... I want to save a file that is not manually uploaded by the user.

In the front-end form, I set the value of the file field to the Blob I want to save, and it tells me that:

**Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.**

Is it even possible to do such a thing?